# Number of tcp connection accepts more than number of connection requests in output of netstat

Tags: tcp

So I ran `netstat -s` in the process of learning and actually looked through the output and found something rather puzzling: for tcp, the number of "connection accepts" is a little more than the number of "connection requests".

How can this be possible? How can a system accept more connections than were requested?? I could upload a screenshot of my terminal, but I found the next best thing: [a link from IBM where the same thing can be noticed in sample output](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/netstat.htm) and [another documentation page with example output](http://www.frascati.enea.it/documentation/tru6450/ARH9GATE/CHNTXXXX.HTM) if you please just Ctrl+F for *accepts*, it's in only one place on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find it's showing incoming "accepts" and outgoing "requests"